# What is the camera_rgb_optical_frame?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the frame supposed to represent? And what is the placement of it in a camera? If you have a big camera  (relative to the raspberry camera) like a Logitech C920, where would this frame be defined? I tried defining it as the lens, but this doesn't add up with my measurements. Is the camera_rgb_optical frame behind the lens? I'd imagine it is the image sensor but would like it confirmed because I could not find info about it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395930/what-is-the-camera_rgb_optical_frame?/) by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2022-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What is the camera_rgb_optical_frame? [..] I'd imagine it is the image sensor [..]

Well, it's not the sensor, but the TF frame which is supposed to represent the *location* of the sensor which captures RGB images.

Or: it's the TF frame which represents what the camera's *driver* reports as being that location -- as an OEM camera driver might post-process a raw image and thereby change certain characteristics.

So it's not the location of the lens, as that's not typically where the sensor is.

To decompose the name:

- `camera`: indicates this is a frame inside of/related to a camera
- `rgb`: this is a (plain) RGB camera/sensor (so not an IR or 3D/depth camera)
- `optical`: the camera can have multiple frames, but this one is the location of the "optical sensor"
- `frame`: well, this resource is a *frame*, a TF frame to be precise, hence the suffix

You'll see this frame name being used in many places which accept standardised TF configurations for cameras, both regular RGB (ie: 2D) and depth (ie: 3D) cameras. I've also seen it used for laser scanners (1D, 2D and 3D) and other optical-like sensors.

Variants of the frame exist, such as the `camera_ir_optical_frame` (for cameras using structured light, or other sensors which have an IR sensor).

There are a couple of REPs which mention it, such as [REP 103: Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions - Coordinate Frame Conventions - Suffix Frames](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#suffix-frames) and [REP 119: Specification for TurtleBot Compatible Platforms](https://ros.org/reps/rep-0119.html). There is no single REP which standardises this though, afaict. The use of the frame is more by convention, and it's a de-facto standard within the ROS community.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3